# typeahead.js limit autofill to items in dataset

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I have a [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) project working, I am able to search. Within this I am pre-filling a second input (using an ID column).

I need a way to detect if the user goes back and alters the filled information but does **not** choose an item from the typeahead list so that I can clear this hidden field.

Example:

- User types "project 1"
- "My Project 1" is displayed as a suggestion and user selects suggestion.
- Hidden field is set to ID of this item (1)
- User returns to field, and types in "something else"
- user does not select any suggestions presented

Currently there is no trigger supplied by Typeahead.js that presents me with the second scenario. Is there another way to detect this?